# Scroll to top in scrollview when click on any button in swift

Tags: swift, scroll, position

In a `ScrollView` I am showing list of views, and at the bottom of that `ScrollView` there is a `CollectionView`. When I click any item in the `CollectionView`, `ScrollView` needs to move to the top. However, it's not scrolling.

I Have been using below code in action:

```
let topOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

scrollView.setContentOffset(topOffset, animated: true)

self.viewDidLoad()

self.viewWillAppear(true)
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: try this 
scrollView.scroll(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: true)

Comment: Out of topic but dont call viewDidLoad or any hierarchical functions manually